# Want to click all buttons with certain class with chrome Console. Is this possible?

Tags: html, jquery, css, selector, google-chrome-console

I am trying to click all buttons with this class:btn btn-primary collapsed

```
<button class="btn btn-primary collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseDetall">
                                                    Detalle
                                                </button>
```

The only difference between this and other buttons is the innerText and Class. I tried putting this on the Chrome Console without success. Due to limitations I``m not able to inject JS from Selenium or other sources, I just can use Chrome console.

```
$(function(){
    $('.btn btn-primary collapsed').on('click',function(e){

    });
})
```

I tried to look into the css for the button ID or name without success. It´s encrypted. Any help appreciated

Comment: Space in selector means "child" - try `$('.btn.btn-primary.collapsed')`

Comment: Thank you , that was the thing I was missing. The correct command is $(".btn.btn-primary.collapsed").trigger("click");
post it and I will give you the upvote . What a boss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved like this

```
 $(".btn.btn-primary.collapsed").trigger("click");
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript way

```
document.querySelectorAll('.btn.btn-primary.collapsed').forEach(elem => { 
    elem.click() 
});
```